# Can anyone recommend an online code editor?

Tags: editor

I have tried many different online wysiwyg editors. And many of them have HTML edit mode. But I am looking for an editor (it doesn't have to have WYSIWYG) that I can use in an online tool to edit html/javascript/css.

Ideally, it should have:

- Support for tabs (press tab to indent code)
- Color coding for various languages
- Not try to execute embedded javascript when run

Any suggestions? I have tried so many but none that have what I want.

EDIT: To be clear, I need code to add to my code. Not an online editor somewhere. This is for a CMS I am developing.

Comment: Just do a search for `online ide`

Comment: Oh wait, are you looking for an editor you can embed in a web page?

Comment: Yes. I have several but am looking for one with those specific features mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one searching other solutions on this forum. Thanks!

http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/

Comment: please give the result if you don't mind

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is the link...

http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/

Answer (score -1):

Firebug is a really good online editor I used it for firefox it was amazing i highly recommend it!